# How to pass JSON string via Angular $http using a variable instead of function(param)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, ajax, angular-http

I have a JSON object like so:

```
var newContact = {"contact_name":"Joe","contact_cell_phone":"4651354"}
```

And I need to pass it through to C# ASP backend using Angular $http.post such as:

```
$scope.Add = function (newContact) {

        // I am passing in this string variable "newContact_string", not the function param "newContact"
        var newContract_string = JSON.stringify(newContact);

        $http
            .post('Default.aspx/AddDb_contact', { newContact_string: newContact_string })
            .success(function (data) {
                console.log("New contact was added with id: " + data.d);
            })
            .error(function () {
                console.log("An error occurred adding the new contact.");
            });
    };
```

However, I am hit with this error in the JS console, specifically referring to this line of code:

```
ReferenceError: newContact_string is not defined
>> $http.post('Default.aspx/AddDb_contact', { newContact_string: newContact_string })
```

My C# backend code is never reached:

```
[WebMethod]
public static object AddDb_contact(string newContact_string)
{
    return newContact_string;
}
```

Perhaps it is a syntax error? How would I go about AJAXing the Angular way?

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo.

You declare `var newContract_string = JSON.stringify(newContact);`

but you pass `newContact_string`.

You need: `{ newContact_string: newContract_string }`

Comment: @KangzeHuang another set of eyes is always helpful :).